# React and Storybook working with both TSX and MDX files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I'm picking up a project with has a custom setup using React, NextJS, and Storybook. I'm trying to add TypeScript and use both "x.stories.tsx" and "x.stories.mdx" for the stories (storybook-addon-docs). I've got the TSX files working, but the MDX ones complain about the loader being used. Do I need a specific loader for the MDX files and if so what? Reading around people say it should work by default.... but it doesn't appear to be. I'm guessing it's using the "awesome-typescript-loader" to try loading the MDX file but any help would be good.

webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = ({ config }) => {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: require.resolve('awesome-typescript-loader'),
        options: {
          configFileName: './.storybook/tsconfig.json'
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx');
  return config;
};
```

config.ts

```js
import { configure, addParameters } from '@storybook/react';

const req = require.context('../src/components', true, /\.stories\.(tsx|mdx)$/);

function loadStories() {
  req.keys().forEach(req);
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```